# Mobile view of Dynamic Form is not consistent with Desktop View Salesforce

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, servicecloud, sales-cloud

For some reason the salesforce app mobile view is not showing the correct fields from the Dynamic Forms. Using Dynamic forms I have renamed the section headers and also added some filters across fields but when I view in mobile version, it shows only what's there in the Page Layout and not picking up from the Dynamic form. Any workaround on that?

Answer (score 0):

`Don’t place Field Section components on mobile-only Lightning pages. Field Section components are desktop-only and don’t appear when the page is viewed on a phone.`

`You can use one Lightning page for both desktop and phone. Add the Record Detail - Mobile component to the same page with your Field Section components. Your desktop users see the Field Section components, and your mobile users see the Record Detail - Mobile component.`

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_considerations.htm&type=5